# D2L Valence: retrieving Final Adjusted Grade Values

Tags: desire2learn

We are retrieving grade values from the D2L grades using the following route:
GET /d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/grades/(gradeObjectId)/values/(userId)

Once the grades are retrieved a conditional test is done to see if the GRADEOBJ_T = 8 (Final Adjusted Grade). If it is, the result is returned to the program. If GRADEOBJ_T ≠ 8, the value is converted to a blank grade and the blank value is returned to the program.

We have just encountered a problem with this when the Grades “Settings” within a course have been modified. If the Grades “Settings” have been changed to release the Final Calculated Grade rather than the Final Adjusted Grade, the route does not retrieve the Final Adjusted Grade it retrieves the Final Calculated Grade. We do not want this.

Is there a route that can be used to specifically retrieve the grade value for the “Final Adjusted Grade” (no matter which final grade is released)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this route:

GET /d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/grades/final/values/(userId)

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for the response. My apologies, I made a mistake. This route (GET /d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/grades/final/values/(userId)) is the one we are using, and it retrieves the released grade rather than the adjusted grade.